# How to pick the first value in repeatable groups of 0 and 1 in several periods

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, analytics

I have the df which has index with dates and values 0 or 1. I need to filter every first 1 from this data frame in several time periods
For example:

```
date            val  period
2019-08-12        0  0
2019-08-13        1  0
2019-08-14        1  0
2019-08-15        0  1
2019-08-16        1  0
2019-08-19        1  0
2019-08-20        0  0
2019-08-21        1  0
2019-08-22        1  1
2019-08-23        1  0
2019-08-26        0  0
2019-08-27        1  0
2019-08-28        1  0
2019-08-29        0  1
2019-08-30        0  0
```

Each 1 in `period` means the beginning of a new time period.
I am interested to get the first row where `val == 1` in each such time period:

```
2019-08-16        1  0
2019-08-22        1  1
```

This is tricky because the place where the first `val == 1` occurs may be later than the beginning of the period. For example, the date `2019-08-16` is selected, even though `period == 0`, because it is the first date where `val == 1` in that period that started on `2019-08-15`.

Comment: Well, show us Your code. What exact issue(s) are You having? This is not "free code writing as a service", You know?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```py
def f(df):
    df = df.assign(gp=df['period'].cumsum())
    df = df.loc[(df['val'] == 1) & (df['gp'] > 0)]
    return df.drop_duplicates(subset='gp', keep='first').drop(columns='gp')
```

On your data:

```py
>>> f(df)
            val  period
date                   
2019-08-16    1       0
2019-08-22    1       1
```